# Problems installing ruby with rvm install 2.6.1

Tags: ruby

Whenever I try to install Ruby 2.6.1 on Ubuntu this error keeps coming up. Does anyone have any solutions?

```
$ rvm install 2.6.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/20.04/x86_64/ruby-2.6.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/rvm/log/1624238816_ruby-2.6.1’: Permission denied
tee: /usr/share/rvm/log/1624238816_ruby-2.6.1/update_system.log: No such file or directory
Updating systemddsmith password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': ..-
..
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.6.1',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1624238816_ruby-2.6.1/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`
```

Comment: Any chance you installed rvm with sudo? you shouldn't

Comment: I second this -- the fact that you're seeing `Permission denied` *probably* means you ran the installation with `sudo` (and, as per the documentation, shouldn't have). You could potentially fix this by running some `chmod` commands, but it might just be easier to uninstall ruby then reinstall **without `sudo`**.